# Birthday probability for three

Tags: probability

There are 32 students in a class-room. What is the probability that at least 3 of them have their birthdays in the same month?
How to get the total possibilities?

Comment: Hint: 2*12 = 24.

Comment: Didnot get  it?  why 2*12 ?

Comment: Do you mean month or date? 25 would be a sufficient number in the standard Gregorian calendar, however in the Bahá'í calendar there are 18 months and then this is a legitimate probability problem.

Comment: Same months mean in ay date of that month.  So if we cross 24, then the probability will still 1? 
Can anyone show me this details mathematically?

Answer (score 4):

The probability is $1$ by the pigeon-hole principle. If order to have at most two students per month, there cannot be more than 24 students.

Comment: so, 3 of them can not have the birthday in the same month?

Comment: @mathphy On the contrary, it is impossible to avoid having at least three in the same month (that' what probability $1$ says)

Comment: I wanted to get it by the law, 
$P =\frac{possible* outcome}{total*possibilities}$

Comment: From my guess, i get the probability more than one,

Comment: @mathphy Of course the probabiliy cannot exced one. For a discussion how to compute such a probability when a computation is necessary in the first place, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/birthday-probability